# FFmpeg: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg

I am making an app which auto-converts videos recorded from another program. I am trying to use command line to exec ffmpeg conversion. This is the command I am typing to the console:

```
cmd /c "C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Converter\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\Users\Mark\Videos\Arma 3\Arma 3 05.10.2015 - 16.27.24.06.DVR.mp4" -b:v 15M -y "C:\Users\Mark\Videos\Converted\Arma 3 05.10.2015 - 16.27.24.06.DVR.mp4.avi"
```

It returns error message

```
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

If I run that command without *cmd /c* part, it works like it should. I also tried adding */s* but without success.

**EDIT**

I solved the problem using Apache Commons library (Java) for executing commands in Command Line.

Comment: Yes, that dir exists. As I said, if I run the command without cmd /c it's working.

Comment: I'd suggest that using `cmd /c` is removing one level of quotes. This has no effect on the executable since there are no separators in its name, but breaks the argument. I'd suggest doubling the quotes in the arument or using `start "windowtitle" ...ffmpeg...` possibly with the `/wait` switch as desired.